# Should this drl compile?

Tags: java, drools, mvel

I'm working on a project that runs Drools 5.5 for a promotion engine system. I'm having some trouble trying to understand the compilation step when i'm building the KnowledgeBase.

This is the case: I have a drl that performs a collect (LHS) on a list with the condition size >= int. 
The system that generates the drl, did it wrong and now i'm having runtime exceptions. Now, i'm trying to understand how the compilation works on drools for this case.

The thing is, on this collect, the constraint (size >= something , where something is not an integer) is not validated by the drools 5.5 compiler, and the exception will only explode in runtime:

```
$COLLECT_ALL : ArrayList (size >= something)
    from collect ( Product ( ... ) )
```

But, the same code is validated on drools 5.0.0 and i'm able to remove this rule before the KnowledgeBase creation.

**I don't know if that is a bug or just a miss understanding of the LHS on drools.**

Anyway, this is the validation step that i'm working on

```
 KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
 builder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(rule.getBytes()) , ResourceType.DRL);
 if (builder.hasErrors()) {
    createErrorMessage(builder);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The DRL parser has undergon a long series of improvements after 5.0.0, and then there was a complete redesign between (IIRC) 5.2 and 5.3.

In order to understand what happens with `ArrayList(size >= something)` in 5.5 at compile time and at runtime, one has to know what "something" is. A complete discussion of everything in place of "something" is out of scope, but, as a rule of thumb, if the expression is valid Java, it should compile and not grumble, rumble or tumble at runtime - let alone "explode" (let's hope it didn't damage a core).

**Later**

The reason is that (somewhere along the line of development) a distinction has been made, not to apply "type safety" to Collections whereas all other classes are "typesafe" by default, which implies compile-time checking.

You can turn this on using, e.g., for `ArrayList` by adding this to your DRL file:

```
declare ArrayList
@typesafe( true )
end
```

Comment: Technically, it's not a valid java statement. "something" is really something. I know that sounds strange, but its just a word in the file. Looks like a variable, but its never declared. Example: `rule "XYZ" when $COLLECT_ALL : ArrayList (size >= tag-xyz)
    from collect ( Product ( ... ) ) then ... `

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. - It appears there is a difference w.r.t. error reporting. A similar error in `Product` is flagged at compile time. I'm pursuing this on the Drools user list.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried this and now the compiler is complaining :)